# Vue.js run a code in mounted and again for restart functionality

Tags: javascript, vue.js, model-view-controller, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am creating a game in VueJS, where, when the page loads, I want a method to fire, make an ajax call to an external API and create a bunch of data properties. When the player wins the round, I want to them to be able to see a button that allows them to restart the game. I am using a `mounted()` hook to fire the method on page load.

My question is I am not sure how to implement the restart functionality if the game setup and API call are within the `mounted()` function. Is there a way to run the `mounted()` function again?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Abstract your initialization into a method, and call the method from `mounted` and wherever else you want.

```
new Vue({
  methods:{
    init(){
      //call API
      //Setup game
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.init()
  }
})
```

Then possibly have a button in your template to start over.

```
<button v-if="playerWon" @click="init">Play Again</button>
```

In this button, `playerWon` represents a boolean value in your data that you would set when the player wins the game so the button appears. You would set it back to false in `init`.

Comment: Actually it seems everybody recommends to use the `created` hook rather than `mounted` to initialize a component. In particular to fetch data.

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland I think initiating async code is probably better in created vs mounted. Your choice of which to use is dependent usually on whether you need access to rendered elements or not. In this specific case, I think OP just wanted a strategy for reusing code called from either mounted or created.

Comment: Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: It seems the ordering matters.  Having the mounted block after the methods works, before it and it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

With Vue 3 and composition API you could use `onMounted` hook to call a function that could be called later :

```
import {ref, onMounted, watch} from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const win=ref(false)

    watch(win,(newVal) => {
      if(newVal) {
        init()
      }
    })

    onMounted(()=>{
      init()
    })

    function init(){
      //init
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also move `mounted` out of the Vue instance and make it a function in the top-level scope. This is also a useful trick for [server side rendering in Vue](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/vue/axios#with-server-side-rendering).

```js
function init() {
  // Use `this` normally
}

new Vue({
  methods:{
    init
  },
  mounted(){
    init.call(this)
  }
})
```