# Vue Object does not allow datepicker Calendar to pop up

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, calendar, smartadmin

And I am trying to integrate my `vue.js` into the framework and facing some peculiar issues.

I have the following html

```
<div class="row" id="searchDetailsDiv">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="fromDate"
            v-model="searchViewPojo.fromDate" type="text"
            placeholder="From">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i
            class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
       </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="toDate"
                    v-model="searchViewPojo.toDate" type="text"
                    placeholder="To">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                    class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am then initialising datepickers (from the SmartAdmin theme) and the Vue object

```
$("#fromDate").datepicker({
    prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
    nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }

});
$("#toDate").datepicker({
    prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
    nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});


var vueApp = new Vue({
    el : searchDetailsDiv,
    methods : { }
    }) ;
```

The datepicker calendar pops up correctly if I comment the `var vueApp = new Vue({}) ;` lines. The datepicker calendar does not popup after I initialise the vue object.

I wonder, is there a compatibility issue between the vue framework and this theme ?

**var vueApp**, not commented

[image: var vueApp, not commented]

**var vueApp**, commented

[image: var vueApp, commented]

**EDIT**

```
<!-- My Main Page -->

<!-- the spring controller sends a JSTL object searchViewPojo --> 
<script>
var searchViewPojo = JSON.stringify(${searchViewPojo});
searchViewPojo = JSON.parse(searchViewPojo) ;
</script>

<body>
<div>
    <!-- entire view -->
</div>
</body>
<script>

var data;
    try {
        data = {
            searchViewPojo : searchViewPojo,
            domainOrGroupParentsInSelectedClient : []
        }
    } catch (err) {

    }
var vueWrapper = vueAjax(data, callWithinMounted); 

function vueAjax(data, callWithinMounted) {
     var vueApp = new Vue({
        el : searchDetailsDiv,
        methods : { }
        },
        mounted() {
            callWithinMounted() ;
        }) ;
    return vuewApp ;
}


function callWithinMounted() {
        /*
        +------------------------------------------------------------+
        | DATE RANGE PICKER SCRIPT                                  |
        +------------------------------------------------------------+
         */
        $("#fromDate").datepicker({
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }

        });
        $("#toDate").datepicker({
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
}
</script>
```

Now, I am calling the `jquery` for `fromDate` and `toDate` in the `mounted()`. The calendar is now visible, But, when I debug the `vue` (**Inspect element, Chrome**) my `searchViewPojo` is not showing the updated `fromDate`, `toDate` values.

I used : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021907/vue-js-mounted`

**Edit Again**
If I modify the vue object from the Chrome Inspect Element->Vue debugger, then then fromDate changes. But changes from the v-model to the vue object dont reflect.

Comment: Put your jQuery logic into the `mounted()` hook, in VueJS instance.

Comment: Ok, it worked. Can you explain why this is needed ?

Comment: Actually i lost the vue feature. Now when I change the `fromDate`, the `searchViewPojo.startDate` does not change

Comment: Could you post demo somewhere, It'd be much easier.

Comment: I have edited the question, is there anything I can provide you ?

Comment: Where have you declared `searchPojo` property (talking about Vue) ?

Comment: Modified the code to reflect the initialization of vue object

Comment: You should take look at Vue Docs section "Reactivity in depth", and you will see that If you want to make properties reactive, you have to declare them in data object, in Vue instance.I see `data` passed in `vueAjax` but it's not referenced anywhere.