# How to run a js code after vuejs render html changes

Tags: vuejs2

I am using a jquery date picker tool. But it is inside a v-if. When I toggle it on and off if I write this code it does not work.

```
showdatepicker:function(){
    this.datepicker= true;
    $(".jquery-date-picker").datepicker();
}
```

Because when $(".jquery-date-picker").datepicker(); runs vue still did not rendered html and added my datepicker input. But if change it to:

```
showdatepicker:function(){
    this.datepicker= true;
    setTimeout(function(){$(".jquery-date-picker").datepicker();},0);
}
```

It works. Because runs it after html render.

My question: is setTimeout a guaranteed way to do it after html render. Is there a proposed way in vuejs to do this right. I couldn't find any answer from my google and stackoverflow searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nextTick` which will call a function after the next DOM update cycle.

```
this.datepicker = true;

Vue.nextTick(function () {
  $(".jquery-date-picker").datepicker();
})
```

And here is it's page in the documentation [VueJS Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

Answer (score 0):

Vue features triggers, in your case the `mounted()` function could be used. This articles describes how to use it and the whole Vue hook timeline : https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/

A stackoverflow explanation : [Vue JS mounted()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45021907/7477557)